# Laravel seeder not inserting in all columns

Tags: php, laravel

Data is not inserting in some of the columns using model seeder.
I tried to use php artisan tinker to insert data in the database but still not inserting in some columns.

```
class FormSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run($admin_id)
    {
        return Form::create([
            'name' => 'Offer document request',
            'version' => 1,
            'admin_id' => $admin_id,
            'pre_defined' => 1,
            'created_by' => $admin_id,
        ]);
    }
}
```

In controller:

```
$form = new \FormSeeder;
$form = $form->run($userData->id);
```

Data is not inserting in admin_id and pre_defined section.

Comment: what about $fillable in Form model?

Comment: Try to add $fillable = ['name','version','admin_id', 'pre_defined','created_by'] in form model

Comment: why are you calling this seeder directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting the answer here in case someone have same issue as me.

The problem lies in my Model. The $fillable property only had `protected $fillable = ['name', 'version', 'created_by'];`

I changed it to `protected $fillable = ['name', 'version', 'created_by', 'admin_id', 'pre_defined'];`
This resolved my problem.